# Reason for "No index signature" error in TypeScript in "for in" loop

Tags: typescript

Why does TypeScript 4.1.3 complain `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ bar: string; }'. No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ bar: string; }'` about the foo[prop] access in a `for in` loop that by definition processes the properties of the referenced object?

Naturally I could just get rid of the type check declaring the object as `any`, `{[key: string]: any}` or similar but this would again get rid of the type checking altogether.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=7&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiEMC8MDeAoG2YCMCGATgFwwDkBhZGAvgNwYYKEwAUoksADoSFzAEsw8RAEp0WHBwggANgFMAdLJABzVghABtHnwC6ohjQxA

```js
const foo = {
    bar: 'bar'
};

for (const prop in foo) {
    console.log(foo[prop]);
}
```

Comment: you could mitigate this by typing `foo` manually like so: `const foo: Record<string, string>`

Comment: just set     `const foo: any  = { } `

Comment: I'm looking for a clean and type save solution

Comment: just assign `const p = prop as keyof (typeof foo);` and then `console.log(foo[p])`.  Or more condensed one-lienr: `console.log(foo[prop as keyof (typeof foo)]);`. See: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13046

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For [some reason](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13046), `for..in` loops in TS will only iterate over strings, not over `keyof obj`.

Here, since `prop` is just a `string`, rather than `'bar'`, it can't be used to look up on the object.

Since it looks like you don't actually care about the key, only the value, iterate over the values directly instead:

```
for (const val of Object.values(foo)) {
  console.log(val);
}
```

If you want to iterate over a key and its associated value together, use `Object.entries`:

```
for (const [key, val] of Object.entries(foo)) {
  console.log(key, val);
}
```